# How do I get ImetaField to be referenced?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity

I'm in a sitefinity project, trying to make an ImetaField type variable, in order to integrate a date field into my widget.

The error:
[image]

My references and namespace and class header:
[image]

Not sure if this is enough information to go on...
Edit: I guess my main question is, what library do I need to reference for ImetaField?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out, you don't a freakin' ImetaField type to get the date, just use DateTime!

Still, I never found out how to use ImetaField, nor do I know now what it may be used for.

What I learned: googling for code in sitefinity is bad.

Comment: From what I know the IMetaField is only used on form widgets and is not typical used by developers like us. If you are creating a page widget you can just used strongly type properties and facilitate the proper integration with the designer Js file if need. But if the are just string properties for a page widget you don't need a designer at all. Don't mistake uneducated googleing as bad just uneducated.